# IDEA run/debug configuration

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My IDEA run/debug configurations looks like this. The VM options don't work:
[image]

How can i edit this window like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The VM options field is disabled by default. You can enable it under *Modify options*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should select modify options then select Add VM options

[image]